# staggeredgridview change grid number & save data on screen orientation android

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I'm using the `StaggeredGridView` to load image and data via webservice. In portrait mode i have 2 grids, in landscape mode i have 3 grids. I want to save the instance when i change the screen orientation to avoid the synctask from re-execute.
I used:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

but the problem is, in landscape mode i have 2 grids not 3. So what is the correct way to get 3 grids?

Answer (score 1):

```
 app:column_count_landscape="3"
 app:column_count_portrait="2"
```

add these lines in xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

add this in manifest.xml